# nginx proxy pass not working on docker containers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have nginx running in docker container on host machine with IP 192.168.1.2.
And I have some other docker containers running  on the same machine: sonarr, radarr, portainer etc.

In nginx conf I have some rules to allow access to these containers based on local DNS without port.

```
server {
    server_name sonarr.lan;
    location / { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8989; }
}
```

And then I can access sonarr application by typing **sonarr.lan** in browser.
Of course I also put sonarr.lan in static DNS table of my router to allow that.

But I want them to be accessible in different style **server.lan/app**
I try to do like that

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name server.lan;
    root /var/www;

    # docker apps
    location /sonarr/           { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8989/; }
    location /radarr/           { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:7878/; }
    location /jackett/          { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:9118/; }
    location /plex/             { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:32400/; }
    location /qbittorrent/      { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8068/; }
    location /calibre/          { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8083/; }
    location /cops/             { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8084/; } # working
    location /homeassistant/    { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8123/; }
    location /grafana/          { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:3000/; }
    location /nodered/          { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:1880/; } # working
    location /portainer/        { proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:9000/; } # working

}
```

When I try to access sonarr application by typing **server.lan/sonarr** in browser I just see empty page. No error, but also no usual content. Server response 200 and just white blank page with one line of text **Sonarr Ver.**
Radarr has the same problem.
Some of them gives me error 500 or unauthorised error.
On homeassistant - I see background, but no info on the page.
Just 3 applications working as expected.

What is wrong? Why their behaviour is so different?

Comment: Host OS? Windows 10? Linux? macOS?

Comment: I don't feel I understand the problem yet. Does everything work when you call things directly?

Comment: When I call apps directly IP:port or using DNS sonarr.lan everything works well. Host OS is Linux (Synology)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

Is it possible that only some ports are made available on your host (IP)? Or that the port in the container is different from the port on the host? Check with:

```
docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a
```

Or on Linux with "show sockets":

```
sudo ss -ltpn
```

Comment: All ports available, because I can call each application directly IP:PORT

Answer (score 0):

Next guess.

Maybe some web apps have problems with not being served on `/`.

Instead of fixing that:

Try it with subdomains?

```
map $host $port_
{
    hostnames;

    default                  8989;  # sonarr
    sonarr.server.lan        8989;
    radarr.server.lan        7878;
    # …
}

server
{
    listen 80 default;
    server_name ~ \.server\.lan$;
    root /var/www;

    # docker apps
    location /
    {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:$port_;
    }
}
```

Completly untested.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here with some container (adguard), but other works

try to use container IP and not Host IP in proxy pass; then remove root /var/www;